# How to set caption for youtube videos box in css?

Tags: html, css

I have created youtube videos after click an image.

Now i need to show caption at the bottom of image.

Here, what i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/4t22181q/

I can't able to set caption with exact css property.

Can anyone please help me?

My page look like this: http://s9.postimg.org/5hhx5rgvj/Untitled_1.png
Thanks in advance.

Html:

```
 <div class="youtubeV">
    <div class="guideBox">
       <div class="videoThum"> <a href="javascript:;"  rel="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GNb8T5NBdQg?list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810" class="youTubeVideo" ><img src="img/play-1.jpg"/></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">Saina nehwal first match</div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.caption {
    caption-side: bottom;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve you just have to

in your `.guideBox`:

- remove `float:left` - to have caption below image
- add `width:XXX%` - (optional).

**EDIT**:

create a `div` to wrap these 3 items and display it as `table` like

```
 .table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

create property `display:table-cell` to your class `.youtubeV` like this:

```
.youtubeV {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

add a `margin-left:22px` or whatever you want to your class `.caption`

remove `width:240px` from your class `.guideBox .videoThum a`

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vt3x9ozk/)

Comment: From your answer, my page look like this: http://s27.postimg.org/9oahfemg3/Untitled_1.png

Comment: did you check my DEMO?

Comment: yes, but look and feel is totally different. and did you check hover state with your demo?

Comment: I need to show, these three images on one column .. without float:left, i can't do it..

Comment: why didn't call table class name in css,  in your js fiddle, you mentioned just call table right?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking me sorry. either here and in the Fiddle I created a `div` to wrap all your content and named it `table` just because I'm displaying it as a table ( `display:table`...)